# Prove that Dirichlet function is non monotonic.

Tags: real-analysis

We have Dirichlet function which is $1$ if $x$ is in $\mathbb Q$ and $0$ if $x$ is in $\mathbb I=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$.We need to prove that function is not monotonic and is invertible.

For monotonic I tried to get two points $x_1$ from $\mathbb Q$, $x_2$ from $\mathbb I$, and then same for $x_1$ from $\mathbb Q$, $x_2$ from $\mathbb Q$ but I couldn't mathematically prove that it is not monotonic.

For function to be invertible needs to be $x_1\neq x_2 \implies f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$ and $\forall y \exists x, f(x)=y$. But I doubt I did it correctly. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

The Dirichlet function $f$ is not monotonic since $f(0) = 1$, $f(\pi) = 0, f(4) = 1$ where $0 < \pi< 4$.

To find an inverse of $f$, we must find a function $f_{1}$ such that $f_{1}(f(x)) = x$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

1. Observe that $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = 1$, but $f(1/\sqrt2) = 0$ and $0 < 1/\sqrt2 < 1$.
2. In fact, the range of $f$ is $\{0, 1\}$, with $f^{-1}(\{0\}) = \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and $f^{-1}(\{1\}) = \mathbb{Q}$.  Since both pre-images are not a singleton, so it would be impossible to invert $f$.

Comment: I didn't understand so function is not invertible?

Comment: You have two values in the domain evaluated to the same value in the range, so that the "inverse function" can't be defined, as a function only allows one input for each input value in the domain.